# report viewer in windows form not updating even after refresh report

Tags: c#, reportviewer, windows-forms-designer

i am try to generate report via report viewer using click event on button. its working fine. but when i update my data in database report viewer show only old report . i have tried using refresh report too.its not working. i am using table adapter in dataset to populate my data.
this.reportViewer1.Reset();

```
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource2 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
            reportDataSource2.Name = "LedgerBy_partyID";

            reportDataSource2.Value = this.Ledger_by_Party_IDBindingSource;


           // this.ReportDataset.Ledger_by_Party_ID.Reset();


            this.Ledger_by_Party_IDTableAdapter.Fill(this.ReportDataset.Ledger_by_Party_ID, selected_PartyID);

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "proj.userReport.Ledger_ByPartyID.rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource2);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Is the report control hosted in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: no i am using on windows form

Answer (score 4):

I just solved the same problem. I was searching for a few days in internet but I couldn't find a good answer for it. So I hope my post will help somebody to overcome the same problem.

All you need to do - just define manually the connection, refill the dataset and bind the source to reportviewer. Here is my project example:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
    private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\GD Robotics\VisualProjects\GDPolin\GDPolin\PolinaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter reportDBTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [ReportDB]", conn);
        DataTable polinaDBDataSet = new DataTable();
        reportDBTableAdapter.Fill(polinaDBDataSet);
        conn.Close();

        this.reportViewer1.Reset();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\GD Robotics\VisualProjects\GDPolin\GDPolin\Report1.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", polinaDBDataSet);//"DataSet1" is the name of your dataset. Go to .rdlc form>VIEW>Report Data>"Right click on dataset">Dataset Properties
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I didn't need to reset the report viewer.  I only needed to clear the data sources before adding the new one.